# Overwriting OSDK flight control command with RC stick command

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm developing Matrice600Pro OSDK software.

I'm finding the way to overwrite OSDK flight control command with
RC stick command temporarily.

It seems UAV control authority is 100% OSDK or 100% RC and doesn't have Intermediate way.
I want to control UAV automatically(osdk) when operator doesn't touch RC,
and manually when operator is using RC(overwrite).

I think the POI function supports such operation.

Can I implement such operation with OSDK?

Answer (score 0):

Hi，for M600 pro，when the osdk is running，UAV control authority is 100% OSDK.But when you change the switch position,the RC can regain control temporarily.If you needs to use the switch to permanently regain control,logic in the onboard computer should monitor the remote controller flight mode switch and stop sending commands to the aircraft.
Here is the official link: [link](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-control-authority.html)

Comment: To be exact, It seems when osdk obtains control authority, the RC control is still available. After osdk send first flightctrl command, the RC command begin being ignored

Comment: Im trying to do the same, and failing... There seems to be no way, that i can take the RC control